# Is the pm-suspend command equivalent to the GUI suspend option?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I noticed the `pm-suspend` command and was wondering whether this is the same as selecting the sleep option on the main menu.

If not, how does it differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems they are the same, I did a little test to prove that they are the same command

I executed the following command

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

To disable the execute bit and when you select the sleep from the menu the screen goes black, but it does not suspend.

Then renabling it

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

The sleep will work from the menu.